# std::unordered_map not compiling with icc

Tags: c++, unordered-map, concurrenthashmap, icc

Like the title says, unordered_map isn't compiling for me. I get an error saying "error: namespace "std" has no member "unordered_map""

I'm compiling with this command icc test.cpp -std=c++0x

This is the program I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<string, int> map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <unordered_map>
```

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

> Defined in header `<unordered_map>`

Comment: Thanks so much. Why does it need to be included in the header if it's in the std namespace?

Comment: @user2142343 Because it is how the standard library is designed. It needs you to include the necessary header for a particular component in order to use it.